# How to determine which event happens more often?

Tags: statistical-significance, count-data, measurement

I am writing a program that measures how many clock cycles a certain piece of code takes. This varies a lot as a result of all kinds of unknown influences and is by no means a normal distribution; for example, it could be a distribution that has two or three spikes, each 8 clock cycles apart and each with a width of 3 or 4 clock cycles. Nevertheless, after some filtering I arrive in a situation where the number of clock cycles that I measure most often (the highest spike) is both reproducible, and of significance to me. Hence, I wish to determine which 'number of clock cycles'-event happens most often.

Lets assume that there are only two competitors: A clock cycles and B clock cycles. Lets say that N(A) is the number of times that I measured A clock cycles and N(B) is the number of times that I measured B clock cycles. Lets assume that if I'd measure for a very long time that N(A)/N(B) approaches a stable and constant value, for example 0.7, that would mean that event B happens more often than event A.

My question is: how many measurement do I need to do to be 99.9% (or any other certainty value) sure that indeed B occurs more often than A? For example, if I measure only 17 times and I'd measure A 7 times and B 10 times then N(A)/N(B) = 7/10 = 0.7, but that wouldn't mean much because it is possible that in fact event A happens more often over the long run and this was just coincidence.

Comment: The hard part is getting an answer without assuming much about the distribution. You might have some luck replacing the number of clock cycles with it's _rank_. That is, list all measurements in order from smallest to largest, and assign each one a number corresponding to it's position in the list. Your question is equivalent to asking whether A clock cycles appear  with lower rank than B clock cycles, which can be answered with more familiar statistical techniques. This procedure is basically a Kruskal–Wallis H test.

Comment: @Nathan I thought it didn't matter... But in any case, A and B will be the two in the top of that list. I'm only interested in the largest one and when I know with 99.9% certainty that B (the one at the top) occurs more often than A (the second largest one) then surely that is also true for everything below A. It seems to me that my question is equivalent to asking "Suppose I toss an unfair coin, then how often do I have to toss it to be 99.9% sure that it is unfair?" The only numbers that you can use in that is the number of times you got a head and the number of times you got a tail so far.